# C# Socket Programming , sending subsequent request fails

Tags: c#, sockets

I am writing a client library which communicates with the server through sockets. 
I am able to connect with server and send the first request, in response to my first request I receive response successfully. But my second request is never received at the server and my `ReadCallback` is only called when I explicitly exit the server.

Below is the code, please let me know if there is a problem with it, because I am sure there is nothing wrong at the server side.

```
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(host))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(host));

            var remoteEndPoint = ResidueUtils.ResolveEndPoint(host, port);
            _socket.BeginConnect(remoteEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), _socket);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            if (!_socket.Connected)
                throw new Exception("could not connect to the specified host.");

            var connectionRequest = RequestBuilder.BuildConnectionRequest();
            byte[] connectionRequestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(connectionRequest);

            _socket.BeginSend(connectionRequestBytes, 0, connectionRequestBytes.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), _socket);
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            //reset the send event , so we could use it later again.
            sendDone.Reset();

            //read the response
            var responseObj = new ResponseObject { WorkSocket = _socket };
            _socket.BeginReceive(responseObj.Buffer, 0, ResponseObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), responseObj);
            readDone.WaitOne();               
            readDone.Reset();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response))
            {
                var privateKey = ResidueUtils.GetRSAPrivateKey();
                var decryptedResponse = ResidueUtils.RsaDecryptWithPrivate(response.TrimBraces(), privateKey);

                var residueResponse = JsonHelper.Parse(decryptedResponse);
                if (residueResponse.Status == 0)
                {
                    Residue.getInstance().Key = residueResponse.Key;

                    var ackRequest = RequestBuilder.BuildAckRequest();
                    var encryptedRequest = ResidueUtils.Encrypt(ackRequest, Residue.getInstance().Key);
                    var encryptedRequestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptedRequest);
               // this request is never received at the server end
                    _socket.BeginSend(encryptedRequestBytes, 0, encryptedRequestBytes.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), _socket);
                    sendDone.WaitOne();

                    sendDone.Reset();
                    response = "";

                    var ackResponse = new ResponseObject { WorkSocket = _socket };
                    _socket.BeginReceive(ackResponse.Buffer, 0, ResponseObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), ackResponse);
                    readDone.WaitOne();

                    readDone.Reset();
                    var ack = response;
                }
            }
```

#### Callbacks

```
     private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
     {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesSent = socket.EndSend(ar);
            sendDone.Set();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            var state = (ResponseObject)result.AsyncState;
            Socket socket = state.WorkSocket;

            int bytesRead = socket.EndReceive(result);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.Response.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                //socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, ResponseObject.BufferSize, 0,
                //    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

                response = state.Response.ToString();
                readDone.Set();
            }

            else
            {
                if (state.Response.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.Response.ToString();
                }
                readDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

### EDIT 1

As suggested , I have replaced the raw sockets with `TcpClient` and still I get the same issue. One thing I have tried is to send the **second request** before the first one just to make sure if something is wrong with the request itself, But I received a valid response from the server, which means there is nothing wrong with the request itself. Below is my new implementation..

```
 using(_tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port))
            {
                var connectionRequest = RequestBuilder.BuildConnectionRequest();
                byte[] connectionRequestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(connectionRequest);

                NetworkStream stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
                stream.Write(connectionRequestBytes, 0, connectionRequestBytes.Length);

                var data = new byte[4098];
                var bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                var privateKey = ResidueUtils.GetRSAPrivateKey();
                var decryptedResponse = ResidueUtils.RsaDecryptWithPrivate(response.TrimBraces(), privateKey);

                var residueResponse = JsonHelper.Parse(decryptedResponse);
                if (residueResponse.Status == 0)
                {
                    Residue.getInstance().Key = residueResponse.Key;
                    //Residue.getInstance().ClientID = residueResponse.ClientID;

                    var ackRequest = RequestBuilder.BuildAckRequest();
                    var encryptedRequest = ResidueUtils.Encrypt(ackRequest, Residue.getInstance().Key);
                    var encryptedRequestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptedRequest);
                    //var stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
                    stream.Write(encryptedRequestBytes, 0, encryptedRequestBytes.Length);

                     data = new byte[4098];
                     // I receive nothing to read here..
                     bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                }
            }
```

Comment: `_socket.BeginConnect(...); connectDone.WaitOne();` So you are doing sync over async? That does not really make sense, does it?

Comment: thanks for your response .. I am not getting your point.. isn't `_socket.BeginConnect(...)` async ??

Comment: Yes it is. But in the very next line you are waiting for it to finish. You could just as well do that synchronously and it would be even more readable and simpler. If you really want to do all of this async, then do not block.

Comment: As far as working is concern, its working fine. You are right about it, but I am new to socket programming and using the sample code from Mircrosoft's docs.. the real problem is below where I am trying to send another request.

Comment: Yeah, the examples from MS are not always ... let's say "production-ready".

Comment: lolz.. my code is also not yet "production-ready"

Comment: Are you 100% sure, the if-body is entered?

Comment: which if-body,, the one the main method or the other in callback ? ..  as I said I recieve the response for first request..and then I try to send another request (inside if-body) but it never reaches the server..

Comment: `if (residueResponse.Status == 0)` - that one

Comment: yes I enter into the body..and later when I call `_socket.BeginSend(..)`  the control stops at `readDone.WaitOne()` and never enters `ReadCallback`..but If I stop the server the controls goes into the `Readcallback` but I receive nothing.. my server shows that the request was never actually received..

Comment: Of what type is "sendDone"?

Comment: its of type .. `ManualResetEvent`

Comment: Try [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) - although I do not think this is the cause ... it will just reset the events for you automatically.

Comment: Please don't follow the sub-standard MSDN samples. For a first start, use classes like `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` to handle socket communication -- they're far more convenient than raw sockets. It's not really worth debugging all this event-based, old-style async hoopla when you can just use streams.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have edited my question with my latest code using `TcpClient` but still I get the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce a problem with your `TcpClient` based client code using a mock server:

```
   var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);            
    server.Start();
    while (true)
    {               
        var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII) { AutoFlush = true })
        {
            var msg = reader.ReadLine();
            writer.WriteLine("[im an encrypted response]");
            msg = reader.ReadLine();
            writer.WriteLine("[im an encrypted response second bit]");
        }
    }
```

The posted code doesn't seem to use message terminators / length prefixes.

As the protocol seems to be text based, a quick fix is to use newline terminators:

```
    using (var _tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port))
    {
        var stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII) { AutoFlush = true })
        {                    
            writer.WriteLine(RequestBuilder.BuildConnectionRequest());
            var response = reader.ReadLine();
            var privateKey = ResidueUtils.GetRSAPrivateKey();
            var decryptedResponse = ResidueUtils.RsaDecryptWithPrivate(response.TrimBraces(), privateKey);
            var residueResponse = JsonHelper.Parse(decryptedResponse);
            if (residueResponse.Status == 0)
            {                        
                Residue.getInstance().Key = residueResponse.Key;
                var ackRequest = RequestBuilder.BuildAckRequest();
                var encryptedRequest = ResidueUtils.Encrypt(ackRequest, Residue.getInstance().Key);
                writer.WriteLine(encryptedRequest);
                response = reader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Client response [" + response + "]");
            }
        }
    }
```

Although this would require a server change due to the newline delimiters.

Using `UTF-8` encoding would probably be better.

[Edit]

Looks like a [lot more information is needed to understand the actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

My final suggestion would be to use a mock server based on the above first of all:

- Add newlines to messages your client sends temporarily
- Amend the mock server responses so they are more realistic

This will hopefully allow you to demonstrate that the client code can successfully transmit messages over several connections, which is the subject of the question.

Comment: thanks for your work.. I was sending an AES encrypted request to the server which it doesn't send.. but when I removed the encryption it is sending the same request..  does this have to do something with encryption.. though the request is encrypted correctly..

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. You could try testing with the changes I made and without any encryption first.

Comment: the server isn't written by me..
without encryption everything works fine.. i.e. I can send subsequent requests to the server and receive response

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your kind replies and help regarding my issue. I was able to resolve the issue.

Actually the problem infact was in the request. The server expected each request to be delimeted with `\r\n\r\n`. I was adding the delimeter for the first request as it doesn't need to be encrypted. I was also adding the delimeter to the second request but I was first adding the delimeter then encrypting the request and was encrypting the delimeter too.

Once I removed the delimeter from the request then encrypt it and added delimeter to the encrypted request its working fine..